# UpdatePanel PostBack Truncates HTTP Body

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

When a postback in an update panel occurs too quickly, it seems that the ASP.NET client side JavaScript has a bug where the body it sends to the server does not equal the content-length in the HTTP header.  This causes IIS 7.5 to throw an "invalid base-64" exception (for my particular app) when the view state variable gets truncated.  A Fiddler trace shows that the HTTP request is in fact malformed.

In my production cases (it happens on more than one page), it's due to very large view state.  Yes, I can trim that or get rid of it altogether.  But the question is does anyone know *why* the client truncates the body and how to avoid it?

Given that I've added none of my own JavaScript, it seems to me that fault lies in the MS client-side JavaScript.  Note that I've only triggered it in IE8/9 and Chrome and not Firefox -- maybe Firefox uses a different socket library (nspr still)?

Following is an example that I've contrived to illustrate the problem.  I added the page in a "Web Site" and am using VS10 with .Net 4.  I can trigger the issue using IIS7.5 and the VS10 builtin web server.  This example usually truncates at 64k (exactly) but my production pages vary.

In Default.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
  <ContentTemplate> 

     <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" /> 

     <asp:Repeater ID="rptCheckBoxes" runat="server"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
         <br /> 
         <asp:CheckBox ID="cbOne" runat="server" 
                       AutoPostBack="true" 
                       OnCheckedChanged="cb_OnCheckChanged" 
                       Text='<%# Eval("thing") %>' /> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
     </asp:Repeater> 

  </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    { 
        var things = new List<Thingy>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) 
        { 
            things.Add(new Thingy { Thing = i.ToString() }); 
        } 
        rptCheckBoxes.DataSource = things; 
        rptCheckBoxes.DataBind(); 
    } 
} 

protected void cb_OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox; 

    if (cb.Checked) 
    { 
        lblResult.Text = cb.Text; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        lblResult.Text = "not checked"; 
    } 
} 

internal class Thingy 
{ 
    public string Thing { get; set; } 
}
```

Run Fiddler, rapidly click on checkboxes and eventually it shows a malformed HTTP request.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a network-related issue?